# Por que a minha string não é convertida para minúsculas?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


/* 
Lucas Correia
Síntese
Objetivo:Ler o nome de duas pessoas e colocar o primeiro letras maiúsculas e o segundo, em letras minúsculas 
Entrada:Dois nomes
Saida:Primeiro nome em letras maiúsculas e o segundo em minúsculas
 */

#define QTD_NOMES 2
#define TAM_NOME 30

char * leValidaNome();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i=0, j=0;
    char nomes[QTD_NOMES][TAM_NOME];


    for(i=0; i < QTD_NOMES; i++){
        strcpy(nomes[i], leValidaNome());
    }

    for(i=0; i < QTD_NOMES; i++){
        if(i==0){
            for(j; j < strlen(nomes[i]); j++){
                nomes[i][j] = toupper(nomes[i][j]);

            }
        }else{
            for(j; j < strlen(nomes[i]); j++){
                nomes[i][j] = tolower(nomes[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }

    printf("%s\n", nomes[0]);
    printf("\t%s", nomes[1]);

    return 0;
}
char * leValidaNome(){
    char nome[30], *pNome;
    int cont=0, flag = 1;
    do{
        printf("Informe seu nome:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome);

        if(strlen(nome) == 0){
            printf("\nNao invalido!\nDigite algo!\n");
            flag = 0;
        }else{
            for(cont; cont < strlen(nome); cont++){
                if(isdigit(nome[cont]) != 0){
                    printf("\nNome invalido!\nDigite apenas letras!\n");
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }while(!flag);
    return pNome = nome;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando tem muito erro eu não tento procurar erro, eu reescrevo direito, mesmo ainda não resolvendo todos problemas e não otimizando tanto quanto pode. E não sei se entendi o problema, ele não está descrito e o código pode ter indicado outra coisa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define QTD_NOMES 2
#define TAM_NOME 30

int soChars(char *nome, int tamanho) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        if (isdigit(nome[i]) != 0) {
            printf("\nNome invalido!\nDigite apenas letras!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void leValidaNome(char *nome) {
    while (1) {
        printf("Informe seu nome:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome);
        int tamanho = strlen(nome);
        if (tamanho == 0) printf("\nNome invalido!\nDigite algo!\n");
        else if (soChars(nome, tamanho)) return;
    }
}

int main() {
    char nomes[QTD_NOMES][TAM_NOME];
    for (int i = 0; i < QTD_NOMES; i++) leValidaNome(nomes[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(nomes[0]); j++) nomes[0][j] = toupper(nomes[0][j]);
    for (int i = 1; i < QTD_NOMES; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(nomes[i]); j++) nomes[i][j] = tolower(nomes[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n%s\n%s", nomes[0], nomes[1]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UoKgci). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sqcfvsfs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ValidationArray.c).

Parte do problema é o código ser confuso e complicado demais, pode ser mais simples e mais bem escrito.

A alocação estava feita de forma ineficiente e errada, já que alocou o espaço para todas palavras do `main()` basta usar esse endereço para qualquer função escrever.

Simplifiquei o laço da função que lê nomes separando a validação se tudo é caractere, assim elimina *flag*, que é uma praga, então quando é válido, só só da função.

É possível que o fato de não inicializar as variáveis dos laços tenha gerado algum erro, por isso que sempre falo para declarar variáveis e usar em seguida, não declarar antes.

Comment: Valeu, Maniero! Eu já tinha conseguido fazer, mas obrigado pelo toque. Vou dar uma olhada nas coisas que eu fiz de maneira errada ou ineficiente.

Comment: @LucasCorreia você sabe que pode votar em tudo no site? Veja o [tour]